# jQuery "See More.." button for loading more post comments does not work when there is more than one post per page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a "See More..." Functionality for my post comments. I'm wanting to grab the last 5 comments and if there are more than 5 comments I want a "See More..." button to show. When the user clicks the button it will display the next 5, and so on.

I'm able to get this to work when I only have one post with comments on the page. However when I load more posts on the page (each with there own set of comments) my system breaks down.

Here is my code:

I'm using Laravel so here is my view:

```
<div class="comment-box-container">
 <div class="comment-box">
    <button class="see-more">See More...</button>
    @foreach ($type->comments as $comment)
        <div class="user-comment-box">
           // bunch of code to layout the users comment here
        </div>
    @endforeach
 </div><!--comment-box end-->
</div><!-- comment-box-container end-->
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$(function(){
        $(".user-comment-box").slice(-5).show(); // select the first 5 hidden divs
        $(".see-more").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
            e.preventDefault();
            var done = $('<div class="see-more=done"></div>');
            $(".user-comment-box:hidden").slice(-5).show(); // select next 5 hidden divs and show them
            if($(".user-comment-box:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs
                $(".see-more").replaceWith(done); // if there are none left
            }
        });
});
```

In my css im hiding `.user-comment-box { display:none; }`

like I said before this works when only one post with comments is on the page, but not when there is more than one. I'm very new to JavaScript and Jquery and not sure how I can fix this. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$(".comment-box").ready` should be `$(document).ready`, your `.comment-box` will be *ready* as soon as the DOM is. Actually you already use the *ready shorthand* `$(function(){` so no need to ready at all

Comment: Can you make a stack snippet or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yes, this works fine, but do you have separated 'Show more' buttons for every post/comments block? Then you have to change selectors, slightly...

Comment: The posts are dynamic. So all "See More.." buttons are the same. this is a my problem i think

Comment: @xslibx, http://jsfiddle.net/7t8kqv94/4/  Not sure about complete HTML, but this could  help, i guess? Now, every button is related to it's own comments, not to all comments on page... (more precise selectors, that's what you need)

Comment: p.s. so you don't have to change your php (to give unique id's or something) - this (or something similar, depending on your HTML output) should work....

Comment: @nevermind This did the trick! Thank you very much. If you would like, create an answer with this and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you need something like this:

```
$(function(){
       // select the first 5 hidden divs

    $( ".comment-box" ).each(function( index ) {
 $(this).children(".user-comment-box").slice(-5).show();
});

        $(".see-more").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
            e.preventDefault();
            var done = $('<div class="see-more=done">done</div>');
            $(this).siblings(".user-comment-box:hidden").slice(-5).show(); // select next 5 hidden divs and show them
            if($(this).siblings(".user-comment-box:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs
                $(this).replaceWith(done); // if there are none left
            }
        });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7t8kqv94/4/  I have changed your initial code slightly - so, now comments are hidden in EVERY block, and buttons should show only related comments (comments from same block).